# Firebase query example returns useless object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the example from the firebase documentation using queries to work but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using cloud firestore.

This is the result I get: [image: query result]

```
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

citiesRef.doc("SF").set({
    name: "San Francisco", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 860000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "norcal"] });
citiesRef.doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles", state: "CA", country: "USA",
    capital: false, population: 3900000,
    regions: ["west_coast", "socal"] });
citiesRef.doc("DC").set({
    name: "Washington, D.C.", state: null, country: "USA",
    capital: true, population: 680000,
    regions: ["east_coast"] });
citiesRef.doc("TOK").set({
    name: "Tokyo", state: null, country: "Japan",
    capital: true, population: 9000000,
    regions: ["kanto", "honshu"] });
citiesRef.doc("BJ").set({
    name: "Beijing", state: null, country: "China",
    capital: true, population: 21500000,
    regions: ["jingjinji", "hebei"] });


// Create a reference to the cities collection
var citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

console.log(query);
```

I'm expecting to log an object that represents the doc that contains the specified value. But the result always is the same (see attachment), even if I search for a non existing value.
Why is that? I hope someone can explain whats happening here and why the example that is provided in the documentation isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

This is because, with the code in your question, you define (and `console.log()`) a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) object.

You are actually not supposed to directly use this object, but instead:

- Call the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query?authuser=0#get) method to execute the query and get the resulting documents (through a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot));
- Attach a listener for `QuerySnapshot` events, with the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query?authuser=0#onSnapshot) method
- Or, refine this query with other methods like `where()`, `orderBy()`, etc...

You will find the full documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query

So, more concretely, with your current code, you should do something like:

```
var query = citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA");

query.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.empty) {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No document corresponding to the query');
    } 
  })
  .catch(err => {
     console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```